# Update questions about Metadata in Apex!

Tags: discussion, answers

I just noticed something super exciting about Summer '17 - We can [access Page Layout Metadata and Custom Metadata using Apex](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_apex_metadata.htm?edition=&impact=)!

There are just so many questions on this site that can more natively answered.  I haven't played around with the feature, but I'd like to answer a number of these questions on here.  My first thought is to search for `mdapi` to find these, but does anyone have tips on how to find questions that can be answered better now?